# Is there a way to change the borderRadius of the previous screen in a presentation:formsheet in @react-navigation/native-stack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have stumbled upon an issue where i want both the foreground modal sheet and the background modal sheet to be having the same borderRadius. I was able to change the borderRadius of the foreground sheet but not of the background. I have tried the style options in the createNativeStackNavigator, but was unsuccessful.[image]

The above image shows both the foreground and the background modal sheets which i have applied different borderRadius to show the difference.

TLDR: I want to increase the borderRadius of the background modal sheet but was unable to do so.

My navigation Stack code :

```
 <Stack.Screen
   options={{
   gestureEnabled: false,
   headerShown: false,
   contentStyle: {
   borderRadius: 20,
   backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
   }}
   name={HomeStackKeys.DASHBOARD}
   component={Dashboard}
  />
 <Stack.Screen
   options={{
   presentation: 'formSheet',
   headerShown: false,
   contentStyle: {
   backgroundColor: 'red',
   borderRadius: 30,
   padding: margins.general_padding2x,
    },
   }}
   name={HomeStackKeys.SETTINGS}
   component={Settings}
  />
```

I have tried changing the styles in the navigation Stack.Screen options hoping that the style method in the options will be able to fix this but it didn't work.

Comment: There seems to some kind of outer component which has a different borderRadius and I want to be able to change that to match the foreground borderRadius.